# Avoid click for table row

Tags: angular, onclick

I have included a button into the table row. but i want to handle onClick event for them separately. But when i click the button the table row click event is also getting fired. How to only fire only the button click element when button is clicked. Here is the code i'm using currently

```
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
      <div  *ngFor="let data of Data; let j = index;">
            <tr [ngClass]="{onClickMember: data .clicked}" (click)="addData(data , j)">                
              <td width="15%">{{member.name}}</td>
                 <td width="15%"><button class="role-toggle" (click)="changeData(data , j)">{{data .role}}</button></td>

              </tr>
     </div>
</table>
```

Comment: remove click event on tr, u cnt hv two click events when other div is inside the other

Comment: aren't there anyway to do that. i want both of the click events

Comment: I don't think there is, use another button for addData

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass special `$event` object in your (click) function.

`<button class="role-toggle" (click)="changeData($event, data , j)>`

Catch the event in code and stop propogation

```
changeData(event, data, j) {
   event.stopPropagation()
}
```